# How to set palette symmetric gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, palette, symmetric

Do you know how to set a symmetric palette color ?
I mean dark/blue for z=0, red/orange z=1.5 and z=-1.5 and yellow z=3 z=-3
 with still a gradient color between color level.

[image]

If you have any ideas please ? Thanks you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your code so far? Have you checked `help`, especially `help palette`?
Check the following example:

**Code:**

```
 ### defined symmetric palette
reset session
set size square

set palette defined (0 'yellow', 1 'red', 2 'dark-blue', 3 'black', 4 'dark-blue', 5 'red', 6 'yellow')

set samples 100
set isosamples 100

plot '++' u 1:2:(sqrt(abs($1*$2))*1.2-3) w image notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Oh thank you, I had misunderstood the functioning of "palette defined"